# Reference Output as Input for the same Module

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code

I´m having a small challenge by getting an output which should be used as the input for the same module. The Code explains it a bit better

```
var virtualNetworkParams = [
{
  name: vnet1-hub
  resourceGroup: ...
  subnets: [{...}]
},
{
  name: vnet1-spoke
  resourceGroup: ...
  subnets: [{...}]
  peerings = [
  {
  resourceIdFromHubVnet: --> RESOURCEIDFROM VNET1-HUB
  }
]
}
]
module virtualNetworkModule '../templates/virtualnetwork.deploy.bicep' = {
  name: '...'
  scope: resourceGroup(resourceGroupDependency[0].name)
  params: {
    vNetParam: virtualNetworkParams
  }
}

in the other virtualnetwork.deploy.bicep template, there is the following code:

module vNetModule '../../../../Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/deploy.bicep' = [for vnet in vNetParam: {
  name: '...'
  scope: resourceGroup(vnet.resourceGroupName)
  params: {
    name: '${vnet.name}'
    location: vnet.location
    addressPrefixes: vnet.addressPrefixes
    subnets: vnet.subnets
    peerings: vnet.peerings
  }
}
]
output vNetResourceIds array = [for (vNet,i)  in vNetParam: {
  WorkspaceId: vNetModule[i].outputs.resourceId
}]
```

So my question would be now -> how to get the resourceId from the HubNetwork which I have referenced as an Input to the peering for the spoke network?

Answer (score 0):

> How to get the resourceId from the HubNetwork which I have referenced as an Input to the peering for the spoke network:

To achieve your requirement, you need to pass the hub network `resource ID` by storing it in a variable and reference it under `virtual network peering's` block.

*Modified your code as below:*

```bash
param  location  string = resourceGroup().location
var subnetName = 'backendSubnet'
var hubVnetResourceId = resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'vnet1-hub')
var virtualNetworkParams = [
{
    name: 'vnet1-hub'
}
{
    name: 'vnet1-spoke'
}
]
resource  virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2023-04-01' = [for  vnet  in  virtualNetworkParams: {
name: 'network${vnet.name}'
location: location
properties: {
  addressSpace: {
  addressPrefixes: [
     '10.0.0.0/16'
  ]
}
subnets: [
{
  name: subnetName
 properties: {
 addressPrefix: '10.0.2.0/24'
}
}
]
virtualNetworkPeerings: [
{
id: hubVnetResourceId
 }
]
}
}
]
```

*Output:*

[image]